# winrt Grid RowDefinitions change depends on VisualState

Tags: grid, windows-runtime, visualstates

Is it possible to chage Grid.RowDefinition when VisualState changes?
Can I extract Grid.RowDefinitions in style or template for select that I need in story board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly write an attached behavior/property that changes the grid row/column definitions depending on a parameter, but you can also use something like a WrapGrid, VariablieSizedWrapGrid or as I said in an answer to your separate question - you can just have separate grids with different layouts and switch visibilities depending on the visual state.

Answer (score 0):

In your VisualState.Setters

```
<VisualState.Setters>
               <Setter Target="row1.Height" Value="*"/>
</VisualState.Setters>
```

In your Grid.RowDefinitions :

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="row1" Height="auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```